# Sql Query for increase item value price for multiple item

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update, case

I want to write Sql Query for increase item price by percentage.

Scenario is :-

In table, I have 3 coloumn : ID, Item-Name, Price

```
Example : If item-Name is T-shirt, Increase price by 10%

         item-Name is Jins , Increase price by 50%

         item-Name is top , Increase price by 5%
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Otherwise carry on, and don't use '-' in table/column identifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to update the table you can do conditional update.

```
update table_name
set 
price = 
case 
 when `Item-Name` = 'T-shirt' then price+( (price*10) /100 )
 when `Item-Name` = 'Jins' then price+( (price*50) /100 )
 when `Item-Name` = 'top' then price+( (price*5) /100 )
end ;
```

And if you are looking  to show the increased price without doing any update in the table at the time of select then you can do as below.

```
select id,`Item-Name`,price,
case 
     when `Item-Name` = 'T-shirt' then price+( (price*10) /100 )
     when `Item-Name` = 'Jins' then price+( (price*50) /100 )
     when `Item-Name` = 'top' then price+( (price*5) /100 )
     else price
    end as new_price from table_name;
```

Comment: So they're all 'times price divided by 100' ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.ItemName, a.Price, 
        (CASE WHEN a.ItemName = 'T-shirt' THEN (a.price * 10 / 100) 
              WHEN a.ItemName = 'Jins' THEN (a.price * 50 / 100) 
              WHEN a.ItemName = 'top' THEN (a.price * 5 / 100) 
              ELSE a.price 
         END) AS calculatedPrice
FROM tableA a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET price = (price*1.1) where item-Name = "T-shirt";

UPDATE TABLENAME SET price = (price*1.5) where item-Name = "Jins";

UPDATE TABLENAME SET price = (price*1.05) where item-Name = "Top";
```

I think it works...