# I am working in Wordpress and I have a query at this situation

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have almost 1800 products in my website. I want to increase to price of all products by adding 200 in all products regular price. As I have 1700 products I cannot edit them 1 by 1. I need a MYSQL Query for this work

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Use PHP Loop Query for update with `update_post_meta()`  - price is saved id `_regular_price` field

Comment: A similar question has answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27353785/3940406

Comment: This looks like a very simple update query - do you have some problem with a query you have created or are you unaware of UPDATE syntax? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brothers Thanks alot. I was in a rush and could not think properly. Actually the solution was quite simple. This is the simplest answer to my Question that I solved and tested.

> update table_name set col_name = (col_name+200)

Answer (score 0):

Running MySQL query for these works is not recommended. There are easy methods to do this. If anything goes wrong, this might crash your website. Make sure you take a backup before executing SQL queries.

**Option1:**

There are few free Wordpress plugins which can do this job.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/pw-bulk-edit/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-bulk-editor/

**Option2:**

Product Price Bulk Editing (WordPress Dashboard):

This is the easiest solution. You can just do this from the “Products” admin page of your WordPress dashboard.

Go to the “Products” admin page
Tick all the products you want to edit the sale price for
Click on Bulk Actions > Edit
Select “Change Price to:”
Choose “Increase Existing Price by Fixed Amount”
Enter e.g. 200
Update